# Integrating InstantRails with Aptana or any other IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ide, aptana, radrails

So I've been using InstantRails to check out Ruby on rails. I've been using Notepad++ for the editing. Now I don't want to install Ruby or Rails on my machine. Is there any walk through/tutorial on how to integrate Radrails or Netbeans with InstantRails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tutorial: http://ruby.meetup.com/73/boards/view/viewthread?thread=2203432
(I don't know if it's any good.)

And here's one with InstantRails+Netbeans: https://web.archive.org/web/20100505044104/http://weblogs.java.net/blog/bleonard/archive/2007/03/instant_rails_w.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend learning Rails and Ruby itself first, and then picking up something like InstantRails.  Having too many layers when learning something new can make it hard to know what features are part of which language, and potentially confuse you when trying to determine where a bug is occurring.